# What is the meaning of 'a: 'a in generic lifetime parameters?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a strange piece of code:

```
#![allow(unused)]

fn f<'a>() {}
fn g<'a: 'a>() {}

fn main() {
    // let pf = f::<'static> as fn(); // (7)
    let pg = g::<'static> as fn();    // (8)
    //print!("{}", pf == pg);
}
```

The 7th line cannot be compiled if it is uncommented (with the error below), but the 8th line can be compiled.

```
error: cannot specify lifetime arguments explicitly if late bound lifetime parameters are present
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |     let pf = f::<'static> as fn(); // (7)
  |                  ^^^^^^^
  |
note: the late bound lifetime parameter is introduced here
 --> src/main.rs:3:6
  |
3 | fn f<'a>() {}
  |      ^^
```

What is the meaning of `'a: 'a` in line 4?

Comment: The only reference to the error in `f::<'static>` I could find is [in the rusc dev guide](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/early-late-bound.html). It looks like `<'a>` is a late-bound parameter but `<'a: 'a>` is an early-bound parameter, and it's illegal to specify late-bound parameters explicitly. I'm not sure *why* that is, but it might be worth a post in [rust-internals](https://internals.rust-lang.org/), if only because the error message is pretty rough and there might be ideas on how to clean it up.

Comment: You'll get an error in _both_ cases if the lifetime is actually used in a function argument. This simplified example is unlikely to come up in "real" code. The exact error message appears to be a side-effect of changes related to work on GATs.

Comment: Source of the question: https://dtolnay.github.io/rust-quiz/11

Comment: Did you read the description of the problem on dtolnay's website? In particular “By these rules, the signature `fn f<'a>()` has a late bound lifetime parameter while the signature `fn g<'a: 'a>()` has an early bound lifetime parameter — even though the constraint here is ineffectual.”

Answer (score 1):

I have found nothing in the rust documentation to confirm, but it seems that `<'a: 'a>` is short to qualify the output lifetime of the function (cf lifetime output in the documentation).

Here are some tests that seem confirm that :

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

fn f<'a>() {}
fn g<'a: 'a>() {}
fn h<'a: 'a>() -> &'a i32 { &5 }
fn i<'a>() -> &'a i32 { &6 }

fn tst1<'b>() {
   let w:&'b i32 = &6;
   //let pj = f::<'b> as fn();
   let pk = i::<'b> as fn() -> &'b i32;
}

fn tst2<'b>() {
   let pr = g::<'b> as fn();
}
fn main() {
    //let pf = f::<'static> as fn(); // (7)
    let pg = g::<'static> as fn();    // (8)
    let ph = h::<'static> as fn() -> &'static i32;
    let pi = i::<'static> as fn() -> &'static i32;

    //print!("{}", pf == pg);
}
```

This compile with Rustc 1.41.1. It's possible that recent updates impact this.

As you could see, `let pi` and `let pk` compile for `fn i<'a>()`, but not `let pf` nor `let pj` for `fn f<'a>()`.  The `fn i<'a>()` only differs from `fn f<'a>()` as the former returns a value thus implying a output liftetime for the function.

The `tst1` and `tst2` verify this with inner lifetime of a function.

It cannot be 100% sure without documentation reference,   but it seems that if you don't specify a output to your function, you still have, for function's pointers, to have a defined output lifetime, and  `<'a: 'a>` seems implying that.

Regarding  dtolnay quizz thanks to @Konstantin W, it **seems** that output lifetime of the function *become* earlier bounded with `<'a: 'a>` and the compiler doesn't scream in that case when assigning the `'static` lifetime at the pointer assignation.

If that's the case, `let pi` and `let pk` compile for `fn i<'a>()` **probably**
because the `i` function is fully defined in input like output then lifetime assignation could be done at pointer assignation (*or the specified output implies earlier bounding for both input and output timeline*, but I've a hard time believing that). Maybe an undocumented rust lifetime Elision rule too.

Answer (score -5):

The `a` in `'a` is just a name.  You could call it `'mylifetime` or `'golden_eternal_braid` if you want to.  The meaining of any lifetime parameter in that position is just to declare it.  Lifetimes other than `'static` are not defined globaly, so you can't declare a function as

```rust
fn f(param: &'a SomeType) {} // error
```

... but if you declare it, you can:

```rust
fn f<'a>(param: &'a SomeType) {} // ok
```

Of course, you could just as well leave that lifetime to be infered, declaring the function as

```
fn f(param: &SomeType) {}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers what the meaning of `g<'a: 'a>` is.

Comment: In general, `<'a: 'b>` means to define lifetime 'a constrained by lifetime 'b.  In this case, it is only constrained by itself, so it is kind of pointless.

Comment: Then why is it required in order to compile the code in the question? So it's not pointless, it has a meaning.

Comment: As written, the lifetimes of booth `f` and `g` is pointless, but the constraint used on `g` binds it enough to kind of fool the compiler that is has a use.  Line 7 can be fixed by removing the lifetime specifikation, like `let pf = f as fn();`.